# Word order in "I checked the website that I said before offers ..."

Tags: adverbs, word-order

I wrote:

> I checked that website which I said before offers random topics, but none of them attracted my interest.

I am doubtful about the position of "before". Did I use it correctly?

Comment: _Before_ is used correctly, but commas and the use of the _subordinating conjunction_ [as](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as_1) might make the sentence easier to understand: _I checked that website, which **as** I said before offers random topics, but none of them attracted my interest._ However, _previously_ removes some ambiguity: _I checked that website, which **as** I **previously** said offers random topics..._

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Don't "as I said before" and "as I previously said" interrupt the sentence flow? Shouldn't they be set off by commas? "Which offered random topics" identifies the site, doesn't it? Why is a comma needed before it?

Comment: @Rompey That is so, but there is also a danger of, for want of a better term, "overpunctuating!" To my ear at least, this has just too many set-offs: _I checked that website, which, as I said before, offers random topics, but none..._ And (also to my ear) this is just too "uninterrupted" for comfort: _I checked that website which as I said before offers random topics..._ (But note that this is getting close to editorial/proofreading...)

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Thank you very much, sir. I just wanted to check whether I understand the rules of punctuation. When I write in my native language, I try to punctuate my writing according to the rules or express my thoughts differently.

Comment: @Rompey There are a some genuine "rules" regarding commas (see [**here**](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/) for example) but the placing of commas in a complicated sentence sometimes depends as much on rhythm as upon rules. Speaking the sentence aloud is often a reliable guide: a pause calls for a comma. And remember that good writers sometimes "violate" these rules for the sake of style, and with no loss of understandability.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - "good writers sometimes "violate" these rules for the sake of style." Or make their sentences shorter like Lee Child, one of my favorites?

Comment: @Rompey Absolutely, or dispense with commas altogether, as in Hemingway's: _"She had wonderfully beautiful hair and I would lie sometimes and watch her twisting it up in the light that came in the open door and it shone even in the night as water shines sometimes just before it is really daylight."_

Comment: Normally the content of the clause, introduced by "as I mentioned earlier" or "as I said previously" and similar phrases, is something that deserves emphasis.  For the example to be idiomatic, that the website offers *random* topics would have to be an important fact.  Perhaps "a wide variety" would be better than "random".

Comment: @TRomano I am not sure if it is *as I mentioned before*, I try to specify the website by recalling the hearer like *the man that I said before (once) [that] is a world champion, had an accident yesterday*

Comment: @P.E.Dant I am not sure if it is *as I said before*, I try to specify the website by recalling the hearer, like *the man that I said before (once) [that] is a world champion, had an accident yesterday*

Comment: @TRomano +1 for "a wide variety" (or just "a variety") and an excellent point about expected emphasis in an "as I said" clause. (Although I do know people who prefer randomness to variety and can't tell the difference.)

Comment: @TRomano Moreover, it really offers random topics (http://writingexercises.co.uk/subjectgenerator.php). Maybe, *generates random subject* is better.

Comment: _The man, who as I said before is a world champion, had an accident yesterday._ "As" is your friend here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks, maybe "as I said" in English conveys what I try to mean and specifies the subject! anyway it's not like *as I said before, this decision is important* to emphasize something, but just to recall and specify

Comment: The "before" is superfluous here, yes.

Comment: @Ahmad: I am not sure what you mean by  "by recalling the hearer".  I think you might mean "by making the hearer recall". (You should ask about **recall** in a separate question.) If so, yes, the as-phrase "as I said" or "as I have said", is a kind of emphatic that lets the reader know that something you said earlier is going to be repeated, or has been repeated, for the sake of making the idea clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Ahmad wrote in a comment above: "... maybe "as I said" in English conveys what I try to mean and specifies the subject!"

> The cat which, as I said (earlier), is on the third of its nine
>   lives...<sup>fragment</sup>
>
> The cat, as I said (earlier), is on the third of its nine
>   lives.<sup>complete sentence</sup>

I understand the *as*-clause as a clause-level modifier, not a subject-modifier. It can be moved up to introduce the sentence, or placed at the end of the clause:

> The cat is on the third of its nine lives, as I said (earlier).
>
> The cat, which is on the third of its nine lives, as I said (earlier), ...
>
> As I said (earlier), the cat is on the third of its nine lives.
>
> As I said (earlier), the cat, which is on the third of its nine lives, ...

This statements marked <sup>fragment</sup> need an independent clause, and in my opinion, the *as*-clause becomes ambiguous in those situations if not properly situated. Which clause does it modify, the dependent clause about the cat being on the third of its nine lives, or the independent clause? In spoken conversation we could disambiguate with the proper intonation and syntactic pauses. In writing, since the *as*-clause can come before or after a clause, or even interrupt it, it is best to have it come after the independent clause to eliminate such ambiguity:

> The cat, which is on the third of its nine lives, loves tuna, as I
>   said earlier.

There the *as*-clause modifies {The cat ... loves tuna} and so there must have been a statement about the cat liking tuna earlier.

Comment: I don't know! as I said in the comments of the question, I am afraid that  what I mean is something else. suppose you are with your friend and point to a man and say "He is Alex". later, you say to your friend "The man who I showed you before, is there (or died)" to mean "Alex is there". Now substitute "show" with "said"

Comment: The same example with "said", "The man who I said you before is Alex, is John, I mistook". It is what I meant by making the hearer recall about Alex.

Comment: @Ahmad: "The man who I said you" is ungrammatical. You'd want to say "The man who I told you was Alex" or "The man who I said was Alex..."  If you want to add "earlier", "The man who I told you was Alex earlier" or "The man who I said was Alex earlier..." or "The man who earlier I said was Alex" or "The man who earlier I told you was Alex" or "The man I told you was Alex earlier" or "The man I said was Alex earlier" or "The man I said earlier was Alex" or "The man I told you earlier was Alex"